# Is it possible to use reflection with linq to entity?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to clean up my code a little by creating an extension method to generically handle filtering.

Here is the code I'm trying to clean.

```
var queryResult = (from r in dc.Retailers select r);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(firstName.Trim(), ex.FirstName.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(lastName.Trim(), ex.LastName.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(companyName.Trim(), ex.CompanyName.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(phone.Trim(), ex.Phone.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(email.Trim(), ex.Email.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(city.Trim(), ex.City.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(zip.Trim(), ex.Zip.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(country.Trim(), ex.Country.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(state.Trim(), ex.State.Trim()) > 0);
```

It's clearly very repetitious.  So I tried to create an extension method that filtered by a property using reflection.  Here is the method.

```
public static void FilterByValue<T>(this IQueryable<T> obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyValue))
    {
        obj =
            obj.Where(
                ex =>
                    SqlFunctions.PatIndex(propertyValue.Trim(), (string)typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName,
                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase).GetValue(ex)) > 0
                    );
    }
}
```

and it's to be called like so:

```
var queryResult = (from r in dc.Retailers select r);
queryResult.FilterByValue("firstname", firstName);
```

But, I get an error when the linq executes, stating that "GetValue" isn't recognized in linq to entity.

So, is there any other way to clean this up, or do I have to leave it ugly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, yes, you could do it, but you'd need to construct the `Expression` yourself to pass to `Where`.

That said, rather than accepting the property as a string value you should consider instead accepting an `Expression<Func<T, string>>` as a parameter so that you have compile time support for verifying that the selected object is valid.

We'll start out with an expression that represents the generic portion; it'll represent a function with*two* parameters, the object and the value of the given property.  We can then replace all instances of that second parameter with the property selector that we've defined in the actual method's parameters.

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterByValue<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> obj,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> propertySelector,
    string propertyValue)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyValue))
    {
        Expression<Func<T, string, bool>> expression =
            (ex, value) => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(propertyValue.Trim(),
                value.Trim()) > 0;

        var newSelector = propertySelector.Body.Replace(
            propertySelector.Parameters[0],
            expression.Parameters[0]);

        var body = expression.Body.Replace(expression.Parameters[1], 
            newSelector);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            body, expression.Parameters[0]);

        return obj.Where(lambda);
    }
    else
        return obj;
}
```

And this method uses a function to replace all instances of one expression with another in a given expression.  The implementation of that is:

```
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

If you *really* want to accept the property name as a string then just replace the definition of `newSelector` with the following:

```
var newSelector = Expression.Property(expression.Parameters[0], propertyName);
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks.  Now I just have to re-read your answer a few more times to understand it.

Comment: @Smeegs It can help to debug it with some actual values and take a look at the expressions that are created (and possibly even some of the intermediate values I don't store in variables).  It helps to visualize it.  Expressions generally have sensible `ToString` implementations.

Comment: Which assemblies/namespaces are you using?  I see SqlFunctions is in both `EntityFramework.SqlServer` and `System.Data.Entity`... I'm assuming these are different, right?

Comment: @user1467396 I was just quoting the code from the OP in that section.  I don't know which he was using.  The transformations of that expression was the code that I wrote for this answer.