# Can I use reflection in linq to entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Below is my code:

```
public class ExpressionBuilder<T>
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringCondition(string propertyName, string value)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> tempFilter = p => p.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(p, null).ToString().Contains(value);
        return tempFilter;
    }
}
```

I just want build an Expression dynamically. 
When I invoke the method:

```
Expression<Func<plcontrol, bool>> conditions = ExpressionBuilder<plcontrol>.BuildStringCondition("code", "%001")
int count = _db.plcontrols.Count(conditions);
```

System reported error like below:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression."

My question is 
 How can I use reflection in linq to entieies 
or
 How can I reference entity property name dynamically

thanks.

Comment: There is no error on my part. The Expression is working well. Unless I missed something on your code.

Comment: Sorry, error message wrong, I have updated it

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733364/is-it-possible-to-use-reflection-with-linq-to-entity) seems related.